# Need help in understanding this specific descending order selectiion sort of integers

Tags: java, sorting, integer, selection-sort

As said in title, this is a descending sort of integer using selecction sort.This is the program.. I m having difficulties in understanding the steps. Can someone help me in understanding it? Thanks in advance!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Selectionsort_descending
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int i,j,k,m,n;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter any number");
n=sc.nextInt();
int a[]=new int [n];

for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
{
System.out.println("Enter number");
a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
for (j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
{
for (k=j;k<=n-1;k++)
{
if (a[j]<a[k])
{
m=a[j];
a[j]=a[k];
a[k]=m;
    }
}
    }
for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
{
System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? It's not conforming to coding standards, it's improperly indented, it uses unreadable variable names. If you are trying to learn, then this is not written by a professional, you should not be learning from it.

Comment: one of my school friend made it... why bro? what is the prob in the program?  @RealSkeptic

Comment: @rockz3r - Since the swap is done inside the inner loop, it's a bubble sort or something similar. If the swap is done outside the inner loop, it's a selection sort or something similar. See my answer below that includes wiki links with example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would highly suggest to get your code more formatted. In Eclipse it is done by pressing [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[F].

By doing that, your code should look like that (I did some improvements which I will explain then).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Selectionsort_descending {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter any number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
        for (int k = j; k < n; k++) {
            if (a[j] < a[k]) {
                int m = a[j];
                a[j] = a[k];
                a[k] = m;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Firstly I changed the "i <= n-1" to "i < n" because I think it is much more readable like this.

Secondly I declared all variables when they were actually used and not right at the beginning as you did.

In the first for-loop you enter your numbers through the console.

Then you check each number of your Array: (j for Loop)

- go through all numbers which came after this number (k for Loop)
- is the current number  (a[j]) less than a number that is located later in the Array (a[k]) ? → Change positions

  This algorythm is also called "Selection Sort" if you want to read more about it.
  I hope i could help you!

Comment: dude... i told selection sort.. i know how to do bubble sort. i wanted explanation for selection sort. :)  @Linux Nox

Comment: looking at the program.. what u did is selection sort.. but by mistake u told "This algorythm is called Bubble Sort"..

Answer (score 0):

Since the swap is done inside the inner loop, it's a bubble sort or something similar. If the swap is done outside the inner loop, it's a selection sort or something similar. Wiki links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort